# Regex pattern in C# with empty space

Tags: c#, regex

I am having issue with a reg ex expression and can't find the answer to my question.

I am trying to build a reg ex pattern that will pull in any matches that have # around them.   for example #match# or #mt# would both come back.

This works fine for that.  `#.*?#`
However I don't want matches on ## to show up. Basically if there is nothing between the pound signs don't match.

Hope this makes sense.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it assumed that there will be no spaces inside of the hashes?

Comment: What would `be##matched##in##this##and##that###or#the#other#thing#` ? So, it looks like you left out %90 of it.

Comment: Please see my edit below

Comment: @sln 89.79591836734694% to be precise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `*` to match between zero and unlimited characters, replace it with `+`, which will only match if there is at least one character between the `#`'s. The edited regex should look like this: `#.+?#`. Hope this helps!

**Edit**

Sorry for the incorrect regex, I had not expected multiple hash signs. This should work for your sentence: `#+.+?#+`

**Edit 2**

I am pretty sure I got it. Try this: `(?<!#)#[^#].*?#`. It might not work as expected with triple hashes though.

Comment: When I ran that on this sentence from a reg ex site.  Edit the Expression & Text to ##see## matches. #Roll# over matches or the expression for details.  I see this as matching ##see## matches. #

Comment: Do you want the text between the double hash signs to show, or not come up at all?

Comment: I need everything to show.   So for example #content# would return "#content"  but ## would be ignored

Comment: Close, but still getting matches when ##match## is used fore example

Answer (score 5):

Please use `+` to match 1 or more symbols:

`#+.+#+`

**UPDATE**:
If you want to only match substrings that are enclosed with *single hash symbols*, use:

`(?<!#)#(?!#)[^#]+#(?!#)`

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%23)%23(%3F!%23)%5B%5E%23%5D%2B%23(%3F!%23)&i=%23some%20text%23%20%23%23some%20text%20inside%20double%20hashes%23%23%20%23%23%23triple%23%23%23%20%23single%20again%23%20%23mixed%23%23%20%231%23)

*Explanation*:

- `(?<!#)#(?!#)` - a `#` symbol that is not preceded with a `#` (due to the negative lookbehind `(?<!#)`) and not followed by a `#` (due to the negative lookahead `(?!#)`)
- `[^#]+` - one or more symbols other than `#` (due to the negated character class `[^#]`)
- `#(?!#)` - a `#` symbol not followed with another `#` symbol.

Comment: I tried that and get matches in between.  This entire line then matched  ##test## matches. #test#

Comment: Please edit your question to include some concrete examples of the input strings and the desired output. It is not easy to make guesses with regexes.

Comment: I have updated the regex, it works a bit differently from the one accepted as it wouldn't match `#mixed#` in `#mixed##`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[^#]?#.+#[^#]?
```

The [^ character_group] construction matches any single character not included in the character group. Using the ? after it will let you match at the beginning/end of a string (since it matches the preceeding character **zero** or more times. Check out the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Perhaps I didn't read your question correctly, are looking for matches on ##string## or do those need kicked out?